# Can't Add Tab Page To TabControl Inside The Constructor Of My WinForms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, tabcontrol

I have a C# Form application that has a TabControl in the main form. This TabControl is used to display multilple TabPages that contain a CustomControl. This CustomControl is just a Panel with a few buttons and a PictureBox.

Here is a picture of my app when it starts up. As you can see the tab control (the white area) is empty:

[image: App Started With Empty Tab Control]

If the user clicks the "Add Image" button they are presented with an OpenFileDialog to select the image then the *addImage* method is called with the selected file:

```
private void doAddImage()
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = Constants.Global.IMAGE_FILE_FILTER();
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string imageFileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        addImage(imageFileName);
    }
}

private void addImage(string imageFileName)
{
    // Create a new bitmap and image preview custom control. Then create a new tab
    // page and add the custom control to the tab page.
    Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(imageFileName);
    ImagePreviewCustomControl previewControl = new ImagePreviewCustomControl(bitMap);
    previewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFileName));
    tabPage.Controls.Add(previewControl);

    // Insert the new tab page to the right of the currently selected tab page
    int selectedTabIndex = imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex;
    imagesTabControl.TabPages.Insert(selectedTabIndex + 1, tabPage);
    imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex = selectedTabIndex + 1;
}
```

As you can see, in the *addImage* method I create the Bitmap, CustomControl, and TabPage and then insert it into the TabControl.

I start my application, click the "Add Image" button, everything works just fine.

Here is a picture with a tab page added:

[image: App With A Tab Page Added]

While I am testing my app I don't want to have to add an image manually using the OpenFileDialog every time so in my constructor I just call *addImage* with some fixed image file name that I want to test with:

```
public ImageViewerApp()
{
    InitializeComponent();           
    addImage(@"C:\MyImages\Calculator-3-icon.png");
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I try to add the image in my constructor it doesn't show up in the TabControl. The application starts up blank (like the first picture).

As stated above when the application is already running and I click the "Add Image" button it gets added just fine.

I found a property in the TabControl class called *Created* which states:

```
"Gets a value indicating whether the control has been created"
```

So to try and figure out what's going on I write the value of *Created* to the console just before I call *addImage* in the constructor. (I have a custom console for debugging my Form applications.)

```
public ImageViewerApp()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TestConsole.WriteLine(imagesTabControl.Created);
    addImage(@"D:\Development\Work\Other\Stardock\Start8\_downloaded\Calculator-3-icon.png");
}
```

The value of *Created* just before the call to *addImage* in the constructor is:

```
False
```

I put another console output inside the *addImage* method:

```
private void doAddImage()
{
    TestConsole.WriteLine(imagesTabControl.Created);
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    ...
    ...
}
```

The value of *Created* after the app has started and the user presses the "Add Image" button is:

True

Why is it that the TabControl is not *Created* inside my constructor (even after the InitializeComponent() call) and the once the application is running it is *Created*?

*=UPDATE========================================================================*
Based on the suggestion by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) I have added the following code to my *addImage* method:

```
int selectedTabIndex = -1;
if (imagesTabControl.TabCount > 0)
{
    selectedTabIndex = imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex;
}
else
{
    selectedTabIndex = imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex + 1;
}

imagesTabControl.TabPages.Insert(selectedTabIndex, tabPage);
imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex = selectedTabIndex;
```

This doesn't work.
*===============================================================================*

*=UPDATE2=======================================================================*

```
int selectedTabIndex = imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex;
if (imagesTabControl.TabCount == 0) selectedTabIndex = -1;

imagesTabControl.TabPages.Insert(selectedTabIndex, tabPage);
imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex = selectedTabIndex;
```

This causes the following Exception:

```
{"InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: index"}
```

*===============================================================================*

*=UPDATE3=======================================================================*

I tried the folllowing code:

```
int selectedTabIndex = imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex;
if (imagesTabControl.TabCount == 0) selectedTabIndex = -1;

imagesTabControl.TabPages.Insert(selectedTabIndex + 1, tabPage);
imagesTabControl.SelectedIndex = selectedTabIndex + 1;
```

This one doesn't throw an exception but again no tab page added after calling
*addImage* in the constructor.
*===============================================================================*

*=UPDATE4=======================================================================*

I have kindof given up on adding an image in the constructor. So instead I am using an enum  RunMode and a variable RUN_MODE of that type. Then, if RUN_MODE == RunMode.TESTI call a method to add a random image when I click the button. (The OpenFileDialog is not used. I just parse through all the image files in the fixed directory IMAGE_DIRECTORY.

```
enum RunMode { NORMAL, TEST }

private static string IMAGE_DIRECTORY = @"D:\\Work\Images";
...
...
private void doAddImage()
{
    if (RUN_MODE == RunMode.TEST)
    {
        addRandomImage();
        return;
    }
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = Constants.Global.IMAGE_FILE_FILTER();
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string imageFileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        addImage(imageFileName);
    }
}
    
private void addRandomImage()
{
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    List<string> imageFileNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (string file in allFiles)
    {
        bool isImageFile = Constants.Global.IMAGE_EXTENSIONS.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file));
        if (isImageFile)
        {
            imageFileNames.Add(file);
        }
    }
    int randomIndex = new Random().Next(imageFileNames.Count);
    addImage(imageFileNames.ElementAt(randomIndex));
}
```

This works. Now when I click the "Add Image" button during TEST_MODE I skip the
OpenFileDialog and just add a random image.

I would like to understand the issues with TabControl but at this point I just
need to continue development. My current solution works great.

As I person who like to understand everything I would like to use other people's
suggestions so I will keep monitoring this question for a solution.
*===============================================================================*

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, can you see the "invisible" tab?

Comment: Where do you mean for me to put the breakpoint? In the constructor or in the doAddImage() method?

Comment: Right at the constructor. Check the "Locals" tab and see if the Tab is added.

Comment: Okay I will do that now but I am not sure what you mean by "Locals"?

Comment: Never mind. I know what you mean by "Locals". The variable tab.

Comment: Here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NiLBT.jpg

Comment: Okay I put the break point and opened the Locals tab and captured a screenshot of the TabControl values when I hit the break point. Here is a screenshot: http://i31.photobucket.com/albums/c380/michellecatssss/Junk/it-locals-tabcontrol_zps439f3f08-1.png

Comment: why did you add an `else` in the updated code?

Comment: Please see my updated code as it is right now and tell me what I need to change. :)

Comment: Okay I added an *==UPDATE2===* using the code as suggested by Hans Passant. When I run that and try to add an image in the constructor I get the following Exception: {"InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: index"}

Comment: Insert the tab then set the selected index as -1.

Comment: I think what I will do is, instead of calling *addImage* in the constructor I will put a static boolean variable called TEST_MODE. If TEST_MODE is set to true I will make the "Add Image" button just call a method to add a random image rather than making me use the OpenFileDialog to add the image each time. Please see *UPDATE4*.

Comment: Nice work! Next thing you know you will get this one!

Comment: I misspoke. I am using an enum RunMode { NORMAL, TEST } and a variable RUN_MODE. So at runtime if I am in TEST mode I will skip the OpenFileDialog and just add the images randomly when I press the "Add Image" button. @See UPDATE4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the TabControl from the designer and then instead just manually create the TabControl programmatically and add it to the Form immediately after InitializeComponent().  Then after you create the TabControl, call addImage().  Something like:

```
    InitializeComponent();

    TabControl tc = new TabControl();
    tc.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    tc.Size = new Size(100, 100);           
    tc.Visible = true;
    tc.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left |           AnchorStyles.Top);
    this.Controls.Add(tc)
    addImage("c:\pathToImage\image.bmp");
```

Comment: This is a good idea, however, I am going with my solution of just adding the image after the app starts. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem.  That makes sense.  Glad you have a solid workaround.

Comment: Note that if you also have fixed tabs like me, this solution will require you to move the designer-generated code for those tabs to your custom creation code, and it will be harder to edit such tabs later.

Answer (score 2):

JonP's answer gave me the idea to just wait for the window handle to be created before inserting the tab, so I tried some events occuring between Form construction and Tab Control display.

I found it to work with both the `Load` or `Shown` events:

1. Right-click on the Form (the root, not child controls) in the Designer view > Properties > Events (flash icon) > Behavior > enter a method name for the `Load` or `Shown` event and confirm. To generate a `Load` event callback you can also double-click on the Form itself. This should generate something like this:

   ```
   this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
   // or
   this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Shown);
   ```
2. Setup the tabs in the callback:

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Add image (this will call imagesTabControl.TabPages.Insert(selectedTabIndex + 1, tabPage))
       // This must be done on Load event because Insert requires
       // the window handle, which is not ready in the constructor
       addImage(@"path_to_image.png");
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't forget to add a comment onthe callback explaining the problem it solves to prevent someone removing it in the future during a cleanup :-)

Comment: And I forgot to say that in general, you should remember to unregister your callbacks with -= when disposing of objects (the overriden Dispose method seems a good place). In this particular case, you are registering a Form method to a Form event so that's probably not critical, but when registering methods from objects with shorter lifespan, not unregistering would prevent garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem too and have found a workaround; I think it must be a bug with `Insert()`:

1. Don't use `Insert()`, it usually does nothing, use `Add()` instead; this reliably adds a TabPage to the end of the collection.
2. After adding it swap it with the tab position where you actually want it.

```
imagesTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
// Now swap the two tabs:
imagesTabControl.TabPages[imagesTabControl.TabCount - 1] = imagesTabControl.TabPages[selectedTabIndex + 1];
imagesTabControl.TabPage[selectedTabIndex + 1] = tabPage;
```

Your mileage may vary of course :-)



**Stop Press!** An even better fix is to read the class's `Handle` member before calling `Insert()`:

```
var handle = imagesTabControl.Handle;
```

`Insert()` works perfectly after you do that. Obvious isn't it???? The help page for Handle has this possible relevant **Remark** showing that the object actually does something when you read `Handle`:

> The value of the Handle property is a Windows HWND. If the handle has not yet been created, referencing this property will force the handle to be created.

Comment: I can't believe swapping actually works where Insert failed. In my case, the order of the other tabs is important though, so I would have to offset all the tabs after the inserted one to the right (O(N) number of tabs to offset).